# laravel return number and boolean as string

Tags: laravel

in prod version laravel return number and boolean as string !!

Localhost :

`{ "age": 24, "is_admin": 0, }`

Prod :

`{ "age": "24", "is_admin": "0", }`

[image]

Comment: please share you model

Comment: `protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'facebook_id',
        'is_admin',
        'age',
        'avatar',
        'gender',
        'last_activity'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'banned_until',
        'last_activity'
    ];`

Comment: do you have $cast in your model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [Attribute Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting), it provides functionality similar to accessors and mutators without requiring you to define any additional methods on your model. Instead, your model's $casts property provides a convenient method of converting attributes to common data types.

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
protected $casts = ['age' => 'integer','is_admin' => 'boolean'];
```

Comment: but why i need to add $casts? it's the same code in localhost and prod !

Comment: to control casting your self, instead of letting laravel to do that

Comment: yes i know , but it's them same code , so must get the same result ?

Comment: most of the cases yes, but when you see something like this, you should take control, specially if you have different operating system on server